# xsl-fo empty table body (validation exception)

Tags: xsl-fo

I am using the following transformation to create a table from XML

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
    <fo:table-header>
        <fo:table-row text-align="right" font-weight="bold">
            <fo:table-cell column-number="2" text-align="center">
                <fo:block>ColA</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell column-number="3" text-align="center">
                <fo:block>Name</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell column-number="4">
                <fo:block color="red">ColB</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell column-number="5" text-align="center"
                color="red">
                <fo:block width="1cm">%</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-header>
    <fo:table-body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="list/v" />
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

For short, I create one row per "list/v"
My problem is, is there is no corresponding data, I am getting the following exception

```
org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:table-body" is missing child elements. Required content model: marker* (table-row+|table-cell+) (No context info available)
```

Hence my question : **How do you create a valid table without body when no data is available?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following worked evetually:

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
    <fo:table-header> (unchanged) </fo:table-header>
    <fo:table-body>
        <xsl:if test="list/v">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="list/v" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(list/v)">
            <fo:table-cell><fo:block /></fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:if>
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

Comment: I guess not unfortunately

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this can work for you, this removes some strict validations for backward compatibility:

```
fopFactory.setStrictValidation(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation when upgrading an application from fop 0.20.25 to 2.1. 
A quantity of existing generated HTML templates has empty  elements and list/v doesn't work in this instance. (it did get me searching in the right direction though) 
Count(child) does handle the situation:

```
<xsl:template match="tbody">
    <xsl:if test="count(tr)!=0">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tr" mode="tableRow" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="count(tr)=0">
        <fo:table-cell><fo:block /></fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Instead of two `xsl:if`, you do it with one test using `<xsl:choose><xsl:when test="count(tr)!=0">...</xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>...</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>`.  Or you could do `<xsl:template match="tbody">` for the regular case and `<xsl:template match="tbody[count(tr) = 0]">` for the code less travelled.